# What kind of control do I need for a vertical display of a List<CustomObject> with a CustomTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I have a `List<MyObject>`,
which stores

```
class MyObject
{
  public String Headline {get;set;}
  public DateTime MyDate {get;set;}
}
```

I want to display each `MyObject` in a vertical order, so that it looks like a entry in a List, with rounded corners and the values are written over the background image.

I've googled two pictures of what looks close to what kind of display control I want to have:
http://assets.gearlive.com/blogimages/gallery/sonos-iphone-app/sonos-iphone-zone-menu_medium.jpg
http://iconfactory.com/twitterrific_touch/images/screenshot_list.png

What kind of control can I use for this? It's like a Repeater/ListView with a custom template. (Let's assume I don't have any graphic skills. How can I create a rectangle with rounded cornes and a color gradient as a background?)

(I'm new to WPF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want selection, go for an `ItemsControl`. Otherwise use `ListBox`.

`ListBox` inherits from `Selector` which inherits from `ItemsControl` and adds selection functionality.

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="<Binding Headline}" />
                <TextBlock Text="<Binding MyDate}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Code behind:

```
ItemsControl1.ItemsSource = ListOfMyObjects;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should probably use a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx).  then, make a [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for your object type--[here is a nice explanation on DataTemplates](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-3-WPF__The_DataTemplate,_choosing_how_your_data_will_look_like.aspx). You should also make `MyObject` derive from [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) so that when you change a value in the object, it will automatically update your UI.  One other thing, you should probably change from `List<MyObject>` to [`ObservableCollection<MyObject>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252944.aspx) so that the `ListBox` will automaticaly update when you add/remove items